# p4 sync -p does not work under certain conditions in Perforce

Tags: perforce

I have a Perforce depot and connect to a replica server. Therefore I use `p4 sync` with the `-p` flag since replicas don't have a "have-list" of client workspaces. Example:

```
$ p4 sync -p //depot/path/to/branch/...@12345,12345
```

Because I would like to apply all changes from that change list to my current workspace I add the `...@CHANGELISTID,CHANGELISTID` expression to the end.

That works for all sync operations and all branches, but if the change list has a file that gets deleted, I receive this error:

```
//depot/path/to/branch/foo - can't sync -p a file that's synced
```

But I want to delete it. Why does that not work?

From the [documentation](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v15.2/cmdref/p4_sync.html) about `p4 sync`:

> -p
>
> Populate a client workspace, but do not update the have list. Any file
>   that is already synced or opened is bypassed with a warning message.
>
> This option is typically used for workspaces used in processes (such
>   as certain build or publication environments) where there is no need
>   to track the state of the workspace after it has first been synced.

I understand that the file got already synced, but in the given change list its state actually switched to "deleted". For reference, here is the output of `p4 describe`:

```
$ p4 describe -s 12345
Change 12345 by daniel@my_workspace on 2020/02/15 23:09:38

    delete test

Affected files ...

... //depot/path/to/branch/foo#2 delete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `p4 sync -p`, you need to use it consistently -- state is not tracked by `sync -p`, and so if you try to `sync -p` a workspace that has existing sync state, it probably means that you're in a bad place, and `sync -p` will just refuse to do anything (issuing the error message that you saw).

If the error message is accurate, you have not been using `p4 sync -p` consistently (maybe you used this workspace with the main server?).  Here's how to tell:

```
p4 have
```

If you've only ever been using `p4 sync -p`, this will return nothing.  If it returns a list of synced files, it means that at least some of your workspace state is being tracked, and when `sync -p` sees it, it will get concerned that it's making your local files inconsistent with that state.

To discard all your workspace state you can do:

```
p4 revert -k //...
p4 flush #none
```

If `p4 have` says that you have no synced files but `p4 sync -p` says that you do, you may be encountering some sort of bug, and should contact support@perforce.com.

Comment: That makes so much sense! I think you just solved the issue. I assumed `p4 sync` and `p4 sync -p` would always do the same!

Comment: I can confirm now that a `p4 add` command caused the having list geting updated. Do you happen to know if I can add a file without the server telling that I have it? Like a `p4 add -p` or `p4 submit -p`?

Comment: You can't write to files without updating and then reading from workspace state (exception: `p4 populate` is purely depot-to-depot and so no workspace is involved); `p4 sync -p` is meant to only support read-only workspace operations.

Comment: The best practice here IMO is to have a workspace root that you **only** use with the replica server, and **only** do `p4 sync -p` with that workspace.  Have a separate workspace that you use on the main server, and use that to submit files.  You don't want your replica's untracked `sync -p` shenanigans to overwrite the files you're actively working on.